# The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found. when it is installed and inside $PATH

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, manjaro

I am working in Manjaro Linux.

I have a .NET Core project. The solution builds fine when I run `dotnet build .`

However, when I run:

```
dotnet-ef update --project Bejebeje.DataAccess --startup-project Bejebeje.Mvc
```

I get the following strange error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
 - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=manjaro-x64
```

It is strange because I already have the SDKs and runtimes for .NET 5.0 installed.

```
bejebeje|feature/upgrade-to-net-5 ⇒ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.108 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.103 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
bejebeje|feature/upgrade-to-net-5 ⇒ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
bejebeje|feature/upgrade-to-net-5 ⇒
```

Why is this happening? and what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16427

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to have an **ASP.NET** runtime.

It's a bit confusing and easily overlooked, but it says you need an `Microsoft.`**`AspNetCore`**`.App` runtime, and your `dotnet --list-runtimes` only lists `Microsoft.`**`NETCore`**`.App`s.

The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/.NET_Core#It_was_not_possible_to_find_any_compatible_framework_version) mentions:

> This is caused because the runtime is shipped as a separate package in Arch. You just need to make sure you have the `aspnet-runtime` package installed as well.

To install the .NET 5 runtime:

```
sudo pacman -Sy aspnet-runtime
```

or if you need the 3.1 version:

```
sudo pacman -Sy aspnet-runtime-3.1
```

Now there's an ASP runtime available:

```sh
$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]  # <<<
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: Thank you sir!!

Comment: I'm so angry that I overlooked this, thank you so much for ending my suffering!