# Asp.net core 5 with Google cloud App engine flex

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to publish the asp.net core 5 application using visual studio Google cloud plugin  to the google cloud, and facing an issue with the SDK

[image]

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: aspnetcore

env: flex

manual_scaling:

  instances: 1

resources:

  cpu: 1

  memory_gb: 0.5

  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Flex operation projects/fetebird-316806/regions/australia-southeast1/operations/0d5426af-3216-4aac-bc65-104811997b19 error [FAILED_PRECONDITION]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2021-06-23T03:56:20.881Z1405.fr.2: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
```

Quite not sure how to point to the .net core sdk version

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66578692/12857703)?

Comment: I am not sure how to use those command, with visual studio gcp plugin or in a cloud shell

Comment: you can run this on the visual studio command window, [here is a guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019) on how to use it, if needed.

Comment: I am having same problem. Using power Shell on Google App Engine console. All Frameworks are there. Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: this article helped me https://zenn.dev/shimat/articles/4c4e292646f32e