# dotnet swagger tofile vs swagger tofile on ARM Mac

Tags: c#, swagger, apple-m1

Hello wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why running `dotnet swagger` doesn't work on Apple Silicon compared to installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli globally via `dotnet tool install`.

For context I have a .NET 6 API with a PostBuild target in my .csproj file to generate a swagger.json on build which looks like what is show below

```
<Target Name="SwaggerToFile" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU' AND '$(NCrunch)' != '1'" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output doc.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" />
</Target>
```

On Apple Silicon this step fails and you get the following error message

```
 It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
         The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (arm64) was not found.
           - The following frameworks were found:
               6.0.5 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
         
         You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

^ The above doesn't exist as far as I'm aware

However if I install the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli globally and then change the command to `swagger tofile --output doc.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll` it works. Trying to understand why there is a difference here if it's the same CLI tool under the hood.

I only have .NET 6.0 SDKs and Runtimes and am doing nothing fancy with Rosetta.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an M2 Macbook Pro and I needed to add the ff to my `.zshrc` to make swagger CLI work.

`~/.zshrc`

`export PATH="$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH"`

I can't recall the specifics but it had something to do with the path that is being added to the environment variables. In this case, the dotnet tool path should be `$HOME/.dotnet/tools`.

After this change, I am able to use the swagger command by `swagger tofile ...`

Comment: On second thought I don't think we experienced the same issue. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66578692/6138713) might be able to help you. Your installed runtime seems to be `6.0.5` while the project is referencing `5.0.0`. Either update the project's target version or install the arm64 for `5.0.0`